# error in code eclipse android studio

Tags: java, android

This is the problem in android studio

https://j20i.imgup.net/Capture2781.JPG

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on the topic, but as I understand the error message, you are trying to operate with a lower bound for the sdk version of 11, but the library (play-services-ads-lite) requires at least version 14.

You can not build your application to be working on a lower sdk version (without forcefully overriding the requirement). Replace your 
    minSdkVersion 11 
with 
    minSdkVersion 14
and you should be set.

PS: Next time, please put your concrete answer, as well as your configuration in your question and don't just share a screenshot of your IDE. People are willing to put more effort into their answers, if they see you putting effort into your question.